# What is the man saying in this Cantonese cartoon?

Tags: translation, vocabulary, word, cantonese, spoken

I started watching Old Master Q today and came across this scene where they try to get an interview, but I couldn't quite understand what was being said here:

https://youtu.be/OR8nxtw8GjY?t=502

Apparently Old Master Q tells the other guy to shut up, but it sounds like "kuai cou a" but the closest thing I could find was 咪嘈 in my Cantonese dictionary. Is this correct, or is it another word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct 咪嘈(don't be noisy) means "be quiet!"

Master Q was saying "咪嘈呀！"

呀 is a final particle that conveys different emotions, and manners or simply emphasizes the sentence itself to make it more forceful.

BTW, 咪嘈 and 收聲(close your voice) can both be translated as "shut up"

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep both of these in my vocab bank.